# Inverse function for $y=\lfloor x\rfloor+x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find the inverse function of the following function:
>
> $y=\lfloor x\rfloor +x$

I have tried writing down $x$ as $\lfloor x\rfloor +\{x\}$ but didn't get anywhere with that.

A proper hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you draw a graph of your function?  And therefore draw a graph of the "inverse function" to be computed?

Comment: I meant floor of $x$ by $[x]$ sorry for the mistake im new to the site

Comment: @Thomas For some basic information about writing maths on this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Comment: Have you tried @GEdgar's helpful hint? The inverse wasn't clear to me until I tried it.

Comment: There is ni $x$ such that $x+[x]=\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: @marwalix: Correct, so $g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is not onto (where $g(x) = x + \lfloor x \rfloor$).  However, $g$ is one-to-one (easy to see by graphing, or observe that $g$ is strictly increasing), and therefore $g$ is (or induces) a bijection onto its range, so it does have an inverse.

Comment: A one sided inverse is $x-\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}2$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $y = \lfloor x \rfloor + x$, then what can we say about the fractional parts of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: They've ought to be equal i assume?

Comment: @Thomas Yes. You're very close now, try to complete the argument :).